# Why is the scope of a Rust function more general than a

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to pass a function as one of the arguments to another function and I'm running into a `one type is more general than the other` error.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e4074efd53fdf9e43d8f209405745dc0

```
use std::future::Future;

async fn constraint<A, Fut, L>(args: A, lambda: L)
where
    A: 'static + Send,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'static,
    L: Fn(&A) -> Fut + 'static,
{
    lambda(&args).await;
}

fn main() {
    constraint("hello".to_string(), lambda);
}

async fn lambda(_: &String) -> () {}
```

Here is the error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     constraint("hello".to_string(), lambda);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected trait `for<'a> <for<'a> fn(&'a String) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {lambda} as FnOnce<(&'a String,)>>`
              found trait `for<'a> <for<'a> fn(&'a String) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {lambda} as FnOnce<(&'a String,)>>`
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:7:18
   |
7  |     L: Fn(&A) -> Fut + 'static,
   |                  ^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

I don’t want to change the lambda function because I want to be able to call it multiple times in a while loop with a second argument from an input stream, but I can change constraint function.

So far I tried adding a lifetime to the constraint function but I'm not sure if that is on the right path since there should already be a static lifetime on A:

```
async fn constraint<'a, A, Fut, L>(args: A, lambda: L)
where
    A: 'static + Send,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'static,
    L: Fn(&'a A) -> Fut + 'static,
{
    lambda(&args).await;
}
```

Corresponding error:

```
   |
3  | async fn constraint<'a, A, Fut, L>(args: A, lambda: L)
   |                     -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
9  |     lambda(&args).await;
   |     -------^^^^^-
   |     |      |
   |     |      borrowed value does not live long enough
   |     argument requires that `args` is borrowed for `'a`
10 | }
   | - `args` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Also tried to move the argument but got the same error:

```
use std::future::Future;

async fn constraint<A, Fut, L>(args: A, lambda: L)
where
    A: 'static + Send,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'static,
    L: Fn(&A) -> Fut + 'static,
{
    async move {
        lambda(&args).await;
    };

}

fn main() {
    constraint("hello".to_string(), lambda);
}

async fn lambda(_: &String) -> () {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `impl Future` return type of your `lambda` implicitly captures the lifetime of it's argument, but your `constraint` requires it to be `'static` (`Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'static`)

Your `lambda` desugars to something like this:

```rust
fn lambda<'a>(_: &'a String) -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'a {
    async {}
}
```

where it's output has a lifetime bound to it's input argument.

While `constraint` expected the signature to look something like this:

```rust
fn lambda<'a>(_: &'a String) -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'static {
    async {}
}
```

You can just use that last definition (the explicit lifetime `'a` is not required).

I'm not sure if and how you can convey that meaning using `async`